# LINQ - EF join difficulty

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have two tables:

**Phase :**

```
long ID
string Name
```

and another **Activity :**

```
long ID
string Name
long PhaseID
```

I already know the name of the phases and I want to get the activity for those particular phases. Do i add PhaseName to the activity table or do I do it through join in LINQ?

Maybe something like this?

```
var query = from a in entities.Activities
                        join p in entities.Phases on a.PhaseId equals p.Id
                        where p.Name == "Preplanning"
```

... and here im not sure how to finish this query..

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you've provided will use an `Inner Join` to find all Activities where the Phase with Name "Preplanning" exists.
To finish your query you need to add a select clause.

```
var query = from a in entities.Activities
                 join p in entities.Phases on a.PhaseId equals p.Id
                 where p.Name == "Preplanning"
                 select a.Name
```

will return `IEnumerable<string>` of all activity names.

Answer (score 2):

Just select activity, as you want:

```
var query = from a in entities.Activities
            join p in entities.Phases on a.PhaseId equals p.Id
            where p.Name == "Preplanning"
            select a;
```

Here is how [query expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384065.aspx) should look like:

A query expression must begin with a **from** clause and must end with a **select** or **group** clause. Between the first from clause and the last select or group clause, it can contain one or more of these optional clauses: where, orderby, join, let and even additional from clauses. You can also use the into keyword to enable the result of a join or group clause to serve as the source for additional query clauses in the same query expression.

Same as puzzling image:

[image]

With method syntax you don't need to end query with something special:

```
var query = entities.Phases
               .Where(p => p.Name == "Preplanning")
               .Join(entities.Activities, p => p.Id, a => a.PhaseId, (p,a) => a);
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to do a join if you only need data from one of the tables. You can apply a filter instead:

```
var q = entities.Activities.Where(a => 
        entities.Phases.Any(p => a.PhaseId == p.Id && p.Name == "Preplanning"));
```